# Wifi card issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've been running into some very weird problems with my wifi card for... practically ever. Symptoms are as follows:

- Frequent drops in connection speed (it's a 300mbps card, runs at 1mbps most of the time, on most networks it's connected too)
- Often can't find my Wifi network (or any network for that matter)
- After resetting, 9 out of 10 times I can't find it in the device manager anymore and I have to reboot
- Does not function on 5ghz networks AT ALL even though it says it should

Now, externally it looks completely fine. Do you guys think it's fried/faulty? **Is there any software to use with which I could test this? Like Memtest for Wifi Cards?** I searched around but I couldn't find anything.

Also:
The problem is definitely not my AP, I've had these problems with every single AP I ever connected to (by now, that's about 8 with my tower), as for my own AP/Router I fiddled with the settings for days, yielding either the same results or no connectivity at all.

Edit:
About the card, it's a TP-Link TL-WDN4800 N900 WLAN Dual Band PCI-E Adapter, I'm using it in a somewhat rural area (outliers of Regensburg, Germany). The card is about a year old give or take. My PC however, is around the 3 year mark.

Comment: You give general symptoms but then don't bother with the details of what card? internal pci? / laptop? / external usb? Age of the system and card. General conditions around where you are? Rural, where you would not expect to have a bunch of interference, or New York City high rise with 10 floors (or more) of affluent people, all most likely with a wifi router .. eg signal crosstalk issues.  Could it be fried? Sure.

Comment: Sorry, updated my post.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/   with something like that, you can turn your pc wifi into a shared hotspot.. bear with me ... iphone or android, you should be able to get an app that would allow you to see signal strength.  That would help you id what the card is capable of.. if weak signals, then that's a likely candidate.  Meanwhile.. looking to see if there's anything about the card specifically.

Comment: Another thing . can you try using WEP instead of any of the proper modern standards?  If you get by with wep, then more likely something with the driver and the work that is done to support proper more secure connections (AES as example) and that the driver just isn't working right/well.  Also googling the card, throws up a rash of this sort of thing all over the net.  Most likely not the card dead or fried ... but either design or driver problem.  if you have a friend that could loan you a temporary one, that would help you test.. etc..

Comment: I should also say try .. make sure the "allow computer to turn off card" option is disabled.  Go to Network & Sharing -> Change Adapter Settings -> right click your card, and do properties -> should be a "Configure" button - press the button .. look for "Power management" Windows could be turning the card off and on causing problems.

Comment: I have an old wifi card somewhere, I'll have to go look for it. Also, WEP I'd need to try, not sure if my router actually allows me to set that (it's rather restrictive, I can't - for instance - disable the firewall either). If it's a driver problem it must be a problem with the supplied driver, because I've reinstalled it quite a few times. - I'll get back to you once I know more, though if I can't get my wifi to work I might just buy a LAN cable. That will also help me identify problems with my router (though I doubt 8 out of 8 routers I ever used have faulty wifi setups)

Comment: 8 of 8 ouch.. and not to discourage .. I don't by TP Link stuff any more.  Inexpensive, yes, but I've had too many oddities, Access points that have power supplies die within a year, Flaky behavior requiring power reset.  And I'm down on Buffalo too.  After they finally worked out the issues between them and broadcom and started selling again in the States, it was never as good as it had been.  I have some pre-2005 stuff that still runs like a champ from Buffalo but its old 54G stuff so no longer any good for wifi.  Good Luck!!